# twrp crashes while trying to backup files

Tags: backup, twrp, nandroid

Can someone help me with a crashing TWRP backup. I am using [twrp 2.8.6.0](https://dl.twrp.me/i9082/)

I have installed TWRP recovery for Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos gt-I9082, but it keeps failing and rebooting to the phone in the middle of 22% of the backup.

I am running Jellybean 4.2.2 Stock Samsung Android dist.

Has anyone ever faced this problem ?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You are advised to use the latest TWRP available; if that still doesn't work, look around on XDA-Developers for the respective thread of TWRP, and report there.

Comment: hey would you please tell me why the latest [twrp](https://dl.twrp.me/i9082/) is distributed as img files and not as tar or files ? Odin is unable to understand the file unless I give it as a tar file. All tar files contain older releases.

Comment: Consider flashing the img file using the "dd Install Method" described on the [intro page](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxygrandduos.html) itself. Boot your device into the current TWRP recovery so that you could have a rooted adb shell access.

Comment: I have flashed the most recent twrp recovery available for my phone but I am still encountering the same error.

Comment: try to install an old version of the twrp, maybe that it is bug

Comment: @bolzy9 Well I tried with both old and new versions. No change. I have shifted to using CWM.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have a lot of files. Look at the process of creating a backup and pay attention to which folder the process lasts the longest. For me this folder was SuperSU logs folder in which there were thousands of files. When I deleted them my problem was solved (twrp 2.8.7.0).